# karma-teamcity-reporter error : cannot read property 'log' of undefined

Tags: angular, teamcity, karma-jasmine

We have an ASPNET MVC5/Angular2/Webpack application with karma tests build in TeamCity. It used to work fine. Recently it started failing with the error "ERROR [karma]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'log' of undefined". The Karma tests passed on local machine so it's not an issue with the tests itself. We do not update any npm packages (e.g. karma, karma-teamcity-reporter, jasmine, phantomJs or typescript recently) as far as we know. So what could suddenly introduce this error or how to resolve it ?

```
[10:37:04]Step 11/22: Karma tests (Node.js NPM) (2m:26s)
[10:37:04]npm test (2m:26s)
[10:37:04]Executing npm via wrapping shell script
[10:37:04]Starting: cmd /c npm test
[10:37:04]in directory: C:\BuildAgent\work\e1596ec73fa322b3\src\...
[10:37:05]
[10:37:05]> angular2-webpack@1.0.0 test C:\BuildAgent\work\e1596ec73fa322b3\src\...
[10:37:05]> karma start ./test/karma.config.js --reporters teamcity
[10:37:05]
[10:37:09]JavaScript Unit Tests (2m:21s)
[10:37:57]30 08 2017 10:37:56.617:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.5.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
[10:37:57]30 08 2017 10:37:56.625:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
[10:37:57]30 08 2017 10:37:56.638:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
[10:38:04]30 08 2017 10:38:04.077:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket OZsVoe9LOJhG5oVMAAAA with id 45606479
[10:39:30]30 08 2017 10:39:30.278:ERROR [karma]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'log' of undefined
[10:39:30]    at getLog (C:\BuildAgent\work\e1596ec73fa322b3\src\...\node_modules\karma-teamcity-reporter\index.js:112:28)
[10:39:30]    at specSuccess (C:\BuildAgent\work\e1596ec73fa322b3\src\...\node_modules\karma-teamcity-reporter\index.js:67:20)
[10:39:30]    at onSpecComplete (C:\BuildAgent\work\e1596ec73fa322b3\src\...\node_modules\karma\lib\reporters\base.js:89:12)
[10:39:30]    at .<anonymous> (C:\BuildAgent\work\e1596ec73fa322b3\src\...\node_modules\karma\lib\events.js:13:22)
[10:39:30]    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
[10:39:30]    at emit (events.js:191:7)
[10:39:30]    at onResult (C:\BuildAgent\work\e1596ec73fa322b3\src\...\node_modules\karma\lib\browser.js:217:13)
[10:39:30]    at Array.forEach (native)
.....
[10:39:31]npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
[10:39:31]Process exited with code 1
[10:39:31]Step Karma tests (Node.js NPM) failed
```

Comment: Did u fix this bug ? We have the same error. in our teamcity this happens randomly...

Comment: Yes, I managed to overcome this issue.

Comment: Yes, I managed to overcome this issue. The root cause is Karma running angular2 tests in PhantomJS extremely slow. During running tests, if there is a disconnection (which is like 99% in my case), the karma-teamcity-reporter lost the original browser instance and will throw this error. I tried to increase different Timeout, DisconnectTolerance, etc. in Karma config to get the tests continue to run but it won't help this issue with the karma-teamcity-reporter. In the end, I had to replace PhantomJS with Electron which run the tests much faster and no more browser disconnect. Thus, overcome it.

Comment: Could try using ChromeHeadless browser too now. (Would need to have Chrome installed in the CI server too, I guess?)